# How to merge rows using linq, which contains a boolean and a sub list?

Tags: linq

How to merge rows which contains a boolean and a sublist as illustrated below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD9nQ.png)

Input is:

PermissionName: 14,
isAllDepartments: True,
Departments: [{1, false}]

PermissionName: 15,
isAllDepartments: True,
Departments: [{1, false}]

PermissionName: 14,
isAllDepartments: False,
Departments: [{2, false}]

PermissionName: 15,
isAllDepartments: False,
Departments: [{2, false}]

Output I am expecting is:

PermissionName: 14
IsAllDepartments: False
Departments: [{ 1, false }, {2, false}]

PermissionName: 15
IsAllDepartments: False
Departments: [{ 1, false }, {2, false}]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am running out of ideas, tried using Aggregate and GroupBy but can't get it to work

Comment: Can you post sample input as text? I can't open imgur links.

Comment: @dvo, Updated the question with input sample, thank you

Comment: @user2366424 How do you want them to be grouped with the `IsAllDepartments` variable being `True` for `Departments: 1` and `False` for `Departments: 2`?

Comment: dvo, If any of the isAllDepartments is False then output for that merged field will be false. Need to merge the Departments list by Permissions, group by will be on the permission

Comment: I think I got it. One last thing, how are you storing `Departments: [{ 1, false }, {2, false}]` in your object? What is the data type of that property? Is it a Key Value pair of int, bool?

Comment: It is a list which contains int and bool, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a test class called `myObject` and defined it as:

```
public class myObject
{
   public int PermissionName { get; set; }
   public bool isAllDepartments { get; set; }
   public List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>> Departments {get;set;}
}
```

Then I added your sample data to a test list:

```
var list = new List<myObject>();
list.Add(new myObject() { PermissionName = 14, isAllDepartments = true, Departments = new List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>>() { new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(1, false) } });
list.Add(new myObject() { PermissionName = 15, isAllDepartments = true, Departments = new List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>>() { new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(1, false) } });
list.Add(new myObject() { PermissionName = 14, isAllDepartments = false, Departments = new List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>>() { new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(2, false) } });
list.Add(new myObject() { PermissionName = 15, isAllDepartments = false, Departments = new List<KeyValuePair<int, bool>>() { new KeyValuePair<int, bool>(2, false) } });
```

Then I grouped the list items together by `PermissionName` and did a select to merge the other two properties:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.PermissionName })
                    .Select(o => new myObject()
                    {
                        PermissionName = o.Key.PermissionName,
                        isAllDepartments = o.Select(i => i.isAllDepartments == false) != null ? false : true,
                        Departments = o.SelectMany(d => d.Departments).Distinct().ToList()
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

`o.Select(i => i.isAllDepartments == false) != null ? false : true` will select any of items in the group that have `isAllDepartments` set to `false`. If it's not null, there was at least one item found so it's set to false, otherwise true (per comments).

`Departments = o.SelectMany(d => d.Departments).Distinct().ToList()` will merge the lists of departments together and only take the distinct int, bool pairs.